# Cannot get FullWipe to work with Sitecore JSS Tech Preview 4

Tags: jss, deployment

I've setup a Sitecore 9.0.2 solution, and i'm testing out JSS. I'm using code-first, and I'm trying to get FullWipe to work on jss deploys.

According the documentation, i'm supposed to set SitecoreJss.WipeAllowed = true, and set wipeOnImport = true.

These settings are from my showconfig.aspx:

```
<setting name="SitecoreJSS.WipeAllowed" value="true" patch:source="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Configuration.config"/>

<app name="customer" sitecorePath="/sitecore/content/jss-home" useLanguageSpecificLayout="true" graphQLEndpoint="/api/customer" inherits="defaults" wipeOnImport="true" patch:source="customer.deploysecret.config" deploymentSecret="..." debugSecurity="false"/>
```

I was expecting it to delete the previously added app items in Sitecore (or put in recycle bin) on each deploy, but it is not doing so. It simply just appends templates and fields on templates.

Im doing: `jss deploy app -c -d` to deploy my app.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The documentation for full wipe mode has been updated to reflect TP4 usage: https://jss.sitecore.net/docs/fundamentals/dev-workflows/code-first#import-full-wipe-mode

---

It looks like the documentation around wipe is out of date. With TP4, you need to set the `SitecoreJSS.WipeAllowed` config setting to true (as you already have):

`<setting name="SitecoreJSS.WipeAllowed" value="true" />`

But instead of adding the `wipeOnImport="true"` attribute to your app config, you pass the `--wipe` parameter via JSS CLI deploy command.

`jss deploy app -c -d --wipe`

or use the `-w` alias for `--wipe`

`jss deploy app -c -d -w`

We'll get the documentation updated as soon as possible.

Comment: Worth noting as well in TP4+ that the `WipeAllowed` global setting defaults to `true` for Sitecore installs that are in the _Standalone_ role. This is designed to make it easy to wipe while developing, but hard to mistakenly wipe a production site (which would have a _ContentManagement_ role)

Comment: Tested and works beautifully :)